# Deploying a framework to a already ready project in PHP

Tags: php, frameworks, codeigniter-2

I have a fully ready web app which we developed in php. It s fully procedural as I didn't know I could use OOPS to make things efficient (since was a beginner in PHP). Now i have all the files and my friend introduced CodeIgniter, I want to know how do i convert the project and deploy it in this framework. Please suggest a few tips which can reduce the development time.

Comment: That's really hard to answer and depends a lot on your code. If a lot of code just deals with CRUD stuff that's better rewritten in CI style, you'll have to rewrite it. If you have large blocks of very specific code that can be used mostly as-is with a little CI wrapping, you may not have to rewrite that much.

Comment: yup most are crud.. ita a online training app.. assuming i will be converting fully to CI, how do i split the classes? :) 
I mean, if there is a page, should I create 3 files in each model view n controller or can reuse? 
ty for the response.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of doing this. You'll need to sift through your app, extract classes, demarcate portions of your code which handle database interactions, business logic and page design, and even reorganize some database tables (the way the framework expects the database to be structured). This 4 year old presentation may be a good starting point: http://www.slideshare.net/crnixon/dealing-with-legacy-php-applications

P.S. Welcome to SO!